# Calling jQuery .each() on dynamically generated content

Tags: jquery, html

This is my first question, but I've already found this site extremely helpful, so thanks to all of you.

So this is the problem. I have a bunch of dynamically generated divs with textareas that I'd like to iterate through. This function here works on the static test divs that I put in, but not on the dynamically created ones.

```
$jQ('#upload_images_button').on('click', function() {
    var caption_list = [];

    $jQ('textarea.upload_image_caption').each(

    function() {
        caption_list.push($jQ(this).val());
        document.write($jQ(this).val());
    });
});
```

And here's the html for each of those divs:

```
<div class="upload_image_temp_wrapper">                                 
    <div class="upload_wrapper">
        <img src="/images/test/test.jpg" />

        <div class="temp_image_hover_menu">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="upload_image_caption_wrapper">
        <textarea class="upload_image_caption" type="text" placeholder="Add a description..."></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Goodness, I feel like an idiot.

I looked back at the script that was generating the new divs and saw that I forget to assign the textareas a class...

Anyway, thanks for all the help. Appreciate all the quick answers!

Comment: Doesn't make sense, you're fetching a new list of textareas every time you click the button. Should be working

Comment: When are you running the JavaScript code? If you run it before the dynamically created elements exist, it won't apply to them. _Edit:_ I may have my wires crossed here, correct me if I'm on the wrong track!

Comment: How are the new elements being added? Perhaps the class is incorrect (or they don't otherwise match the selector)? Does the selector match if "manually" looking at the in Firebug (or the equivalent for your environment)?

Comment: You can't use `document.write`, that will overwrite everything in the document if called after the page is loaded

Comment: Juan Mendes, I was just using that as a test to see if it was working properly. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @Jazy48 Please do not add `(Solved)` to your question name. You can tell the question is resolved by the check mark next to the first answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine. Your error is somewhere else. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Buaja/

**HTML**

```
<button id="upload_images_button">Upload</button>
<button id="add-div">Add Div</button>

<div class="upload_image_temp_wrapper">                        
    <div class="upload_wrapper">
        <img src="/images/test/test.jpg" />

        <div class="temp_image_hover_menu">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="upload_image_caption_wrapper">
        <textarea class="upload_image_caption" type="text" placeholder="Add a description..."></textarea>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**JS**

```
$jQ('#upload_images_button').on('click',
    function(){
        var caption_list = [];

        $jQ('textarea.upload_image_caption').each(
            function(){
                caption_list.push($jQ(this).val());
                console.log($jQ(this).val());
            });     
    }
);

// Add divs dynamically
$jQ('#add-div').on('click', function() {
   $jQ(document.body).append($jQ($jQ(".upload_image_temp_wrapper")[0]).clone());
});
```

**Note**

- Don't use document.write, that will overwrite everything in the document if called after the page is loaded

Comment: @Jazy48 An explanation of what was wrong with your code would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.on()` like you're doing doesn't bind the event as a live event (because the optional selector argument is missing), which means it will only bind to elements that exist at the time of execution. If you change the way you call `.on()`, specifically binding the click to the `body` instead, you can change the events to be live on the `#upload_images_button` button:

```
$jQ('body').on('click', '#upload_images_button', function() {} );
```

Also, I'm not sure if you've got multiple `#upload_images_button` buttons on your page or not, but remember IDs have to be unique, so if you do have multiple of these elements, use a class instead of an ID.

Comment: See my comment, why would you need to use `$.on`? The handler is on the button itself, I'm pretty sure the error is something else

Comment: He didn't specify *which* elements he is adding dynamically. The rest of the code is fine, which makes me assume that the button is the element he's adding dynamically.

Comment: He did, he said the HTML in the question is generated dynamically divs

Comment: Like I said, the rest of the code is fine, so I made an assumption that the button is being added dynamically too. We'll need to wait for more information from the OP before we know what the exact problem is.

Comment: Your assumption goes against what is stated in the question. Just saying...At least, you should have explained that in the answer, otherwise, the answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, you guys, for the late response. The divs are the only things being added dynamically. There is only one '#upload_images_button', and it is NOT generated dynamically.

Comment: One more thing, don't call it a `live` event, `live` is deprecated, the correct term is delegation (through event bubblling)